# How to change an order of workspaces?

Tags: desktop, workspace, show-desktop, multitasking-view

Can I, for example, replace workspace 1 by workspace 3 in the multitasking view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, this is not possible under elementary OS. You could file a feature request; however, keep in mind that developers might want to keep it clean.